# How to format time in a dynamically generated php description?

Tags: php, datetime, joomla, date-format

I am currently using:

```
<? JFactory::getDocument()->setDescription($event->title . " am " . $event->start, 'end' -> $event->end) ?>
```

this generates following:

```
<meta name="description" content="event title am 2017-12-12 15:30:00">
```

but I need the time to be in this format:

```
12.12.2017 um 15:30 Uhr
```

how can I archive this?
I know that the Dates for the Event are rendered with this code:

```
helper('date.from_till', array('start' => $event->start, 'end' => $event->end, 'format' => $params->date_format))
```

I would really appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Question got answered with another Question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47752218/8207054

```
$doc->setDescription($event->title . " am " . date('d.m.Y', strtotime($event->start)) . ", " . date('H:i', strtotime($event->end)) . " Uhr");
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change format and then pass it to `setDescription`. You can simply do it by changing format with `DateTime`

```
<?php
  $date = new DateTime('2017-12-12 15:30:00');
  echo $date->format('d.m.Y \u\m H:i').'Uhr';
?>
```

Demo : https://eval.in/916535

OUTPUT :

```
12.12.2017 um 15:30 Uhr
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. How can I apply this to the Dynamically Generated Time? Because at the Moment your Answer is based on the Static Time "2017-12-12 15:30:00". How would this look with the setDescription? I am sorry for such a stupid Question, but I am very new to PHP and at a stage where I am trying new stuff :)

Comment: You need to pass date time from ie.`$event->start` or `$event->end`. I am also new in php I just started 2 month ago. Still looking for job.

Answer (score 0):

oh sorry, this should work, I've tested it:

```
<?
    $date_object = new DateTime($event->start);
    JFactory::getDocument()->setDescription($event->title . " am " . ($date_object->format("d.m.Y \u\m H:i \U\h\\r")), 'end' -> $event->end);
?>
```

Comment: I get this Error "Call to a member function format() on string"