# How to set a third operator in a String that adds the Text "Uhr"?

Tags: php, string, joomla, operator-keyword

I need to add "Uhr" at the end of the following Code:

```
<?
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
            $doc->setTitle($event->title . " | Example");
            $doc->setDescription($event->title . " am " . $event->start, 'end' -> $event->end "uhr needs to be here");
?>
```

how can I archive this? Because if I add a `.` "Uhr" it doesn't work :(

Comment: `if I add a . "Uhr" it doesn't work ` do you get any error?

Comment: @urfusion no, it just doesn't get added.

Comment: What output you are expecting ?

Comment: @urfusion `<meta name="description" content="event am 2017-12-12 19:30:00 Uhr">`

Comment: as per your comment  `$event->end. "uhr needs to be here"`.  remove `'end'->`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$doc->setDescription($event->title . " am " . $event->start . ", " . $event->end . " Uhr");
```

should do it.

Formatted dates:

```
$doc->setDescription($event->title . " am " . date('d.m.Y', strtotime($event->start)) . ", " . date('H:i', strtotime($event->end)) . " Uhr");
```

Comment: if I do this it looks like this: `<meta name="description" content="event am 2017-12-12 19:30:00, 2017-12-12 21:00:00 Uhr">* so it doubles the time.

Comment: Then you'd need to format your dates: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-format.php

Comment: How can I format the dates with this code? I am extremely new to php and don't know how things like this are done :(

Comment: @YoKoGFX: edited my answer to use formatted dates (first one is date only, second one is time only)

Comment: Typo, sorry, fixed it

Comment: Kein Problem! ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something wrong with the last `->`. 
Maybe this works:

```
$doc->setDescription($event->title . " am " . $event->start, 'end' . $event->end . "uhr");
```

Answer (score 0):

In case `"am"`, `"end"` and `"urh needs to be here"`, best you use the same quotes like:

```
<?
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->setTitle($event->title . " | Tanzschule Hartung");
$doc->setDescription($event->title . " | Tanzschule Hartung" " am " . $event->start, "end" -> $event->end . "uhr needs to be here");
?>
```

(*look at your text 'end', compared to the code above*)

It looks like `$event->start` (and others) need to display some text which is requested.

Why you need to use a `.` (dot) after requesting text from another function is because PHP needs to understand when it has to display text or not.

The `.` is the string concatenation operator.

This might work as well:

```
<?
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
// Setting titles
$title = $doc->setTitle($event->title);
$start = $event->start;
$end   = $event->end;

$doc->setDescription($title . " | Tanzschule Hartung am " . $start . " , end" . $end . "uhr needs to be here");
?>
```

I hope this clears something up.

If you have any questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: I can understand what you are trying with this solution but it breaks the page without an error.

Comment: See the last code, did this work? If it's not you need to check if the variables `$title`, `$start` and `$end` are set by adding `var_dump($title)` just below `$title` and see if any results are given. This need to be debugged.